# Why they use left join instead of inner join in this code

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm newbie in sql... This query seems to run completely fine with inner join, and then why the author still chose left join ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM {$wpdb->posts} notices

LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} instances 
ON ( notices.ID = instances.post_id AND instances.meta_key = 'mycred_email_instance' )

LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} pointtype 
ON ( notices.ID = pointtype.post_id AND pointtype.meta_key = 'mycred_email_ctype' )

WHERE instances.meta_value = %s 
AND pointtype.meta_value IN (%s,'all') 
AND notices.post_type = 'mycred_email_notice' 
AND notices.post_status = 'publish'
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: "INNER JOIN" can't get records that instances (or pointtype) don't have records. But "LEFT JOIN" can fill in joined records by using "NULL". So the author may think that he have chance to use records contain "NULL". For example, he may think that show alert "You should register your credit card information".

Comment: I think the author may use pointtype table's columns (except meta_value). Other columns may be NULL. Because "SELECT * From..." get all columns.

Comment: Yes !  You are right. It might be that way. The alert "You should register your credit card information" is such a good example.